# Does rails 3 find_by_x sanitize data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a few basic fields:

- title
- category
- etc.

I have seen documentation that says when you do:

```
Model.where("category = ?", params[:cat])
```

the code will be sanitized automatically.  If I convert the above to:

```
Model.find_by_category params[:cat]
```

will the params also be sanitized automatically?  I don't want to *assume* that it is because that would be a bad security mistake.

Comment: Yes it does sanitize. Since you are on Rails 3, check it in the console. It will show you the generated SQL statement and by looking at it you can determine whether the sanitization took place or not.